# What happened to William Giles?

Tags: character, oz

In the TV series Oz, the character William Giles was put on death row, requested death by stoning, which lead to a new law by the state.

He was last seen in the beginning of Season 5, where he won a fight against Alvarez.

What happened to him after that? Maybe I missed a dialog where someone talked about him? Or is his fate open?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you've missed anything according to his [character page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Giles_%28Oz%29). Same exact text is on the [OZ wiki](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/William_Giles).

Comment: That was such a great show, and the first time I saw Chris Meloni, JK Simmons and Harold Perrineau.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**His character was just crossed out of the show** after the penultimate season's opener *Visitation*. It's been a while, but if memory serves, no reason is ever given for this. From the [trivia section for *Visitation* on TV.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/oz/visitation-109743/):

> This episode marks the last appearance of the great supporting character William Giles. **He is never even spoken of again** until the audio clips at the very end of Exuent Omnes, which is an old clip from season 2.

Giles's [wikia page](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/William_Giles) corroborates it:

> Last appearance: "Visitation" (episode 5.01)
>   Reason/Cause: **End of Storyline**